# how to set up an environment variable that it stores a path along with another env variable but doesnt expands

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I want to know how to set up an environment variable that stores other environment variable but these environment variables doesn't gets expanded when I echo instead if I use `eval echo` then it should expand.

Like i want to have `echo $TEST_HOME` should result in `/Users/krysto/$PATH/$DATA_DIR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `TEST_HOME` using single-quotes to prevent bash expansion:

```
$ TEST_HOME='/Users/krysto/$MYPATH/$DATA_DIR'
$ echo $TEST_HOME
/Users/krysto/$MYPATH/$DATA_DIR
```

Then, one can use eval to expand it.   As an example:

```
$ MYPATH=dir1/dir2
$ DATA_DIR=data/dir
$ eval echo $TEST_HOME
/Users/krysto/dir1/dir2/data/dir
```

*A couple of notes:*  The convention is that the important system variables, like `PATH` or `HOME`, are all upper-case.  If you want to avoid overwriting one of them, make your variables lower-case.  In particular, overriding PATH could leave the shell that you are in largely non-functional.

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the variables (makes no diffirence if local or env), e.g.

```
> test="echo something"
> test1="\$test"
> echo $test1
$test
> eval $test1
something
```